# QuickSight - Average daily total

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

I have the following data in my spice database and im trying to get the average daily cost of AWS.

```
Resource          Cost    Date
AWS CloudTrail    9      2020-08-27
AWS Cost Explorer 1       2020-08-27
Amazon DynamoDB   3.50    2020-08-28
AWS Lambda        16.50    2020-08-28
```

With the above example the average daily cost would be 15 taking the sum of each day then getting the average however, with the average function in Quicksight i'm getting an average of 7.5 since its not taking the total daily cost.

Is there anyway I can get a simple text box containing only the average cost per x days without using tables.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a calculated field
the syntax is:

avgOver
(
sum(Cost),
[Date]
)

Comment: I don't see how this custom field can be used in a graph. Dragging this into the autograph returns `table calculation attribute reference(s) are missing in field wells`. When dragging the Cost field in to a autograph it shows me the sum.

Comment: In the graph you must have the field in which you need the aggregation over. For our example it is the date. So it sums th cost and average per day