# Quicksight - Calculate Average of Max(value) in a Day

Tags: amazon-quicksight

I have a table with the following fields
[image]

What I am wanting to do is calculate the average delay by person, but taking the highest delay of each day.

So if on 2023-05-01 Peter had 5 Items and the max delay for any of those items was 2, then I want to count that 2 towards the average. If on 2023-05-02 Peter had 3 items and the max delay for those 3 items was 1 then 1.

So if I then calc the average delay for items over the month of May it's effectively average(2,1)

I am however having some trouble putting this in a Calculated field in Quicksight.
I have read up and it would seem maxOver should be on my radar, but something as simple as

`avg(maxOver({delay_in_days},[{submitted_for},date],PRE_AGG))`
is returning the average of all items over the period and not just the average of all the maxes for a given day.

I also reviewed an example given in this post
[QuickSight - Average daily total](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63684612/quicksight-average-daily-total?rq=2)
but, there I ran into more errors than solutions

any direction on how to approach this differently or am I missing an additional step?